# GraphQL Object Identification

Tags: javascript

При использовании graphQl возникла необходимость создать query вида:

```
movies(id:"RW50aXR5QWdncmVnYXRpb246VGhlIENvbWViYWNr") {
    name
}
```

Не получается искать по id, который присваивает элементам graphQL, работает вот такоей вариант:

```
{
  node(id:"RW50aXR5QWdncmVnYXRpb246VGhlIENvbWViYWNr") {
    id
        ...on EntityAggregation {
        name
      }
  }
}
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы graphql работал по первому примеру?

schema:

```
movie: {
            type: new GraphQLList(EntityType),
            args: {
                id: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLInt) },
                audience: {
                    type: GraphQLString, // TODO: declare enum
                    defaultValue: "OVER_18"
                }
            },
            resolve: function (_, args, ctx) {
                return ctx.execute(search.searchEntities(args))
                    .then(result => result.entities);
            }
        }

const EntityType = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: "Entity",
    interfaces: () => [nodeInterface],
    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField(),
        type: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(EntityTypeEnum) },
        name: { type:  new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        description: { type:  new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    })
});

export const searchEntities = R.curry(function(
    param: SearchParamType,
    ctx: UserContextType,
    token: string
): Promise<EntityResponseType> {
    const mappedParams = mapProperties(param, mapping, ctx);
    const uri = absoluteUri(config.asUri, searchUri);
    return httpClient.doGet(uri, mappedParams, token);
});
```